# is protected accessible to other classes other than the sub classes?

Tags: java, computer-science

So I know this is a beginner question, but I got confused, because from what I understand is that protected is only accessible to sub-classes / classes that extend the super class .. **but I'm working on a project and weirdly enough, I was able to access a protected instance variable from class A , in class B (class B does not extend class A).**
Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Read [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. As long as the classes are in the same package, protected is accessible, even if they are non-sub classes. But when a class wants to access protected from a different package, then protected is only available to sub-classes.